# MongoDB not connecting without VPN

Tags: node.js, express, vpn, ipv6

I've had this problem for quite a while now since we got a new router, so I thought I might just ask here: I cannot connect to MongoDB via mongoose and other applications without a VPN and it always gives me this error: https://pastebin.com/5fDVk5C0. This is my code for connecting:

```
mongoose.connect(config.mongodb.database).then(() => {console.log("Backend successfully connected to MongoDB");
```

````
    async function createTokens() {
        if (
            !(await tokens.findOne({
                accessTokens: { $exists: true },
                refreshTokens: { $exists: true },
                clientTokens: { $exists: true },
            }))
        ) {
            await tokens.create({});
        } else {
            var jwtTokens = await tokens.findOne({
                accessTokens: { $exists: true },
                refreshTokens: { $exists: true },
                clientTokens: { $exists: true },
            });

            for (var i in jwtTokens) {
                if (Array.isArray(jwtTokens[i])) {
                    for (var x in jwtTokens[i]) {
                        try {
                            await jwtTokens.updateOne({ $pull: { [`${i}`]: null } });

                            let object = jwtTokens[i][x];
                            let decodedToken = jwt.decode(object.token.split("eg1~")[1]);

                            if (
                                DateAddHours(
                                    new Date(decodedToken.creation_date),
                                    decodedToken.hours_expire
                                ).getTime() <= new Date().getTime()
                            ) {
                                await jwtTokens.updateOne({ [`${i}.${x}`]: [] });
                                await jwtTokens.updateOne({ $pull: { [`${i}`]: [] } });
                            }
                        } catch { }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        function DateAddHours(pdate, number) {
            var date = pdate;
            date.setHours(date.getHours() + number);

            return date;
        }
    }

    createTokens();
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error connecting to MongoDB: ", error);
});```
````

It seems like that it's trying to connect via ipv6 in the error, which shouldn't be a problem is my router supports that. I have also had this problem for other programs such as NPM or the EpicGames friends list, they just all do not work without a VPN.

"What did you try and what were you expecting?": I would expect Mongoose to connect normally in my ExpressJS app instead of it giving me a connection error. I know it's not the problem of me whitelisting my IP because the IP of my VPN is not Whitelisted either and it's only in mongoose (Compass works).